# Matrix Algebra for linear regression two regressors of a different variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, parameter-estimation

Suppose I have the following.

$\boldsymbol{y}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
y_{1} \\
y_{2} \\
y_{3} \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
y_{n}
\end{array}\right], \boldsymbol{X}=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & X_{1,1} & X_{1,2} & . & . & X_{1, p} \\
1 & X_{2,1} & X_{2,2} & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
1 & X_{3,1} & X_{3,2} & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
1 & X_{n, 1} & X_{n, 2} & \cdot & \cdot & X_{n, p}
\end{array}\right]$
$\boldsymbol{\beta}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\beta_{0} \\
\beta_{1} \\
\beta_{2} \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\dot{\beta}_{p}
\end{array}\right], \boldsymbol{\epsilon}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\epsilon_{1} \\
\epsilon_{2} \\
\epsilon_{3} \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\epsilon_{n}
\end{array}\right]$

Constructing the linear model $y=X \beta+\epsilon$

$\left[\begin{array}{c}
y_{1} \\
y_{2} \\
y_{3} \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\dot{y}_{n}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} X_{1,1}+\beta_{2} X_{1,2}+\cdots+\beta_{p} X_{1, p}+\epsilon_{1} \\
\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} X_{2,1}+\beta_{2} X_{2,2}+\cdots+\beta_{p} X_{2, p}+\epsilon_{2} \\
\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} X_{3,1}+\beta_{2} X_{3,2}+\cdots+\beta_{p} X_{3, p}+\epsilon_{3} \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} X_{n, 1}+\beta_{2} X_{n, 2}+\cdots+\beta_{p} X_{n, p}+\epsilon_{n}
\end{array}\right]$

Where $\boldsymbol{e} = y-\widehat{y}$ with $\widehat{\boldsymbol{y}}=\boldsymbol{X} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$

Now estimating $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ by minimizing the sum of squared residuals $SSR= \boldsymbol{e}^{T} \boldsymbol{e}=(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}})^{\boldsymbol{T}}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}})$

yields:
$\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}=\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{T} \boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-1} \boldsymbol{X}^{T} \boldsymbol{y}$

Now suppose I have the following model and want to estimate $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ and $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}$ of the following model:

$y=X \beta+ Y\alpha+\epsilon$

With

$\boldsymbol{X}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
 Y_{1,1} & Y_{1,2} & . & . & Y_{1, q} \\
 Y_{2,1} & Y_{2,2} & . & . & . \\
Y_{3,1} & Y_{3,2} & . & . & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . \\
 Y_{n, 1} & Y_{n, 2} & . & . & X_{n, q}
\end{array}\right]$ and
$\boldsymbol{\alpha}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\alpha_{0} \\
\alpha_{1} \\
\alpha_{2} \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\dot{\alpha}_{q}
\end{array}\right]$
Where $p\neq q$

Constructing the SSR yields:
$S S R=\boldsymbol{e}^{T} \boldsymbol{e}=(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}-\boldsymbol{Y} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}})^{\boldsymbol{T}}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}-\boldsymbol{Y} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}})^{\boldsymbol{T}}$

How do I now obtain $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ and $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}$? My initial thaught is to differentiate w,r,t $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ and $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}$ and equating it to 0. However, how do I then solve such a system of equations?

Following the suggestion of agryavian I construct a new matrix:

$Z= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & X & X & X & Y & Y & Y \\
1 & X & X & X & Y & Y & Y \\
1 & X & X & X & Y & Y & Y \\
\end{bmatrix}  $ and $\boldsymbol{\theta}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\beta_{0} \\
\beta_{1} \\
\beta_{2} \\
\beta_p
\cdot \\
\alpha_0 \\
\alpha_1 \\
\dot{\alpha}_{q}
\end{array}\right]$

Should I now perform the SSR like this?:

$ SSR= \boldsymbol{e}^{T} \boldsymbol{e}=(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}})^{\boldsymbol{T}}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}})$

yields:

$\widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}=\left(\boldsymbol{Z}^{T} \boldsymbol{Z}\right)^{-1} \boldsymbol{Z}^{T} \boldsymbol{y}$

Comment: Information comes from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_EH2abOp00&list=LL&index=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second model is the same as "combining" $X$ and $Y$ together into a wide matrix and performing linear regression with respect to it, since
$$X\beta + Y \alpha = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}X & Y\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} \beta \\ \hline \alpha \end{array}\right]$$

In general, the fitted $\hat{\beta}$ in your second model will not be the same as the $\hat{\beta}$ in your first model. (I think the exception is if the column space of $X$ is orthogonal to the column space of $Y$.)

Comment: I have edited the original post to perform your suggestions. Do you agree with this workout?

Comment: @Wietze $X$ and $Y$ should be combined side-by-side, not as a block diagonal matrix.

Comment: I have changed it in the way you proposed I think,

Comment: Could you please confirm this

Comment: @Wietze Check for yourself that $Z\theta = X\beta+Y\alpha$.